# Remove security groups from a list of users, excluding a few

Tags: powershell, active-directory

PowerShell beginner here....

I need to clean up a terminated users OU in AD that contains thousands of accounts. I would like to strip all groups, except 2 specific ones (domain users and a licensing group), from every account.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how this script would look? I have found a few examples online but I can't seem to find anything that explains how to exclude groups.

I found something that allows me to remove a list of folks from a single group..... but I'm not sure how to convert this to something that removes all groups, except the ones I want to exclude.

```
Start-Transcript -Path -Append

# Import the data from CSV file and assign it to variable
$Users = Import-Csv ""

# Specify target group where the users will be removed from
# You can add the distinguishedName of the group. For example: CN=Pilot,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=exoip,DC=local
$Group = groupname

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    # Retrieve UPN
    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName

    # Retrieve UPN related SamAccountName
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
    
    # User from CSV not in AD
    if ($ADUser -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        # Retrieve AD user group membership
        $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.SamAccountName | Select-Object Name

        # User member of group
        if ($ExistingGroups.Name -eq $Group) {

            # Remove user from group
            Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $ADUser.SamAccountName -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
            Write-Host "Removed $UPN from $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            # User not member of group
            Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Well can we see your attempt at this?

Comment: So then why specify a single group if you strip the users from all groups they are a member of? Shouldn't be too hard to exclude certain groups if they are present in the `MemberOf` list for each user (specify that on Get-ADUser with parameter `-Properties`). P.S. adding `| Select-Object SamAccountName` and `| Select-Object Name` is unnecessary and `if ($ADUser)`  is better than `if ($ADUser -eq $null)`

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest way to remove bulk of users from an Azure AD group using PowerShell is:**

Using Remove-AzADGroupMember is faster than Remove-MsolGroupMember.

```bash
Import-Module AzureAD
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
$group=Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'Your Tenant Group Name' 
$users=Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.ObjectId -All $true |where {$_.ObjectType -eq 'User'}
foreach($user in $users){
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.ObjectId -MemberId $user.objectId
}
```

[image]
**Note :** In credentials prompt box, provide the admin id of the tenant and password. If there are lot of users in the group then it is expected to take some time.

---

**Need to Remove the user/users who exists in One or More groups**

If you are doing it for a single User :

```
 $user_upn = "<USER UPN>"
 $users= Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<GROUP B ID>" -All $true

 #Finds for a specific user and if it exists, goes ahead and remove the specific user from the Group A
 $users |?{$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $user_upn} | %{Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<GROUP A ID>" -MemberId $_.objectid}
```

### Explanation

Obtains every member of Group B and puts their information in the variable $users. Checks (Filters) to see if the necessary member is present in the $users variable, and if it is, it removes the member from Group A.

If you are looking to do it for the list of UPNs from a File. You could refer to the below snippet.

```
 #Getting the list of UPNS of the users for whom the process specified needs to be carried out
 $user_upns = Get-Content "C:\ListUPN.txt"
 
 #Iterates through each UPN
 foreach( $user_upn in $user_upns)
 {
 
 Write-Host "Working on the $user_upn" -ForegroundColor Green
 
 #Gets all user from the GROUP B
 $users= Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<GROUP B ID>" -All $true
 
 #Finds for a specific user and if it exists, goes ahead and remove the specific user from the Group A
 $users |?{$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $user_upn} | %{Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<GROUP A ID>" -MemberId $_.objectid}

 }
```

---

Try to remove the users who are in multiple groups so that, to filter and do the removal operation becomes easy!